# Error trying to get access token for system-assigned managed identity

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service, access-token

I am trying to acquire an access token for the system-assigned managed identity of my web app. Here's the code I tried:

```
DefaultAzureCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
{ 
    ManagedIdentityClientId = Constants.ManagedIdentityId,
});
var accessToken = cred.GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://management.azure.com" }));
```

When I try to use this access token to access the API Management REST API, I get the following error:

> The access token is from the wrong issuer
> 'https://sts.windows.net/TENANT_ID1/'. It
> must match the tenant
> 'https://sts.windows.net/TENANT_ID2/'
> associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL)
> 'https://login.windows.net/TENANT_ID2' to
> get the token.

How/where do I set the Tenant ID?

**NB:** At this stage I'm running the code on my dev machine in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

For system-assigned managed identity, it is unnecessary to set  ManagedIdentityClientId and tenantId.

And the correct scope is "https://management.azure.com/.default." maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Found the (rather easy) solution minutes after posting this question. All that has to be done is to specify the tenant ID when creating the `DefaultAzureCredential`:

```
DefaultAzureCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
{ 
    TenantId = Constants.TENANT_ID,
    ManagedIdentityClientId = managedIdentityId,
});
```